# ¿Cómo ordenar por fecha una consulta UNION en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente query:

```
    `select name, lastname, date_charge, description, charge 
     from customers 
     inner join charges on customers.idCustomer = charges.idCustomer
  UNION
     select name, lastname, date_deposit, description, deposit 
     from customers 
     inner join deposits on customers.idCustomer = deposits.idCustomer;`
```

Como resultado me da lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que primero pone los resultados del primer select (los dos primeros) y después los resultados del segundo select (los dos últimos). Lo que quiero es que me ordene los registros por por las fechas que se muestran en la imagen.

Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que es un UNION no hay relacion entre ambos resultados directamente, solo tienes que incluir todo ello en una consulta de forma anidada:

```
SELECT t.* from (
  select name, lastname, date_charge, description, charge 
    from customers 
    inner join charges on customers.idCustomer = charges.idCustomer
  UNION
  select name, lastname, date_deposit, description, deposit 
    from customers 
    inner join deposits on customers.idCustomer = deposits.idCustomer
) t ORDER BY date_charge
```

Comment: Perfecto, funcionó.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma sencilla es dar un nombre único a la columna en la primer consulta y encerrar cada `SELECT` con paréntesis:

```
(select name,  date_charge as fecha
       from customers 
       inner join charges on customers.idCustomer = charges.idCustomer)
union

(select name, date_deposit
       from customers 
       inner join deposits on customers.idCustomer = deposits.idCustomer)

       order by fecha;
```

También puedes consultar la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)